# How to image update using laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

I don't know how to edit image using laravel5. When I update my image file It show this error:

> FatalErrorException in SiteadminController.php line 1719:
>   Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Image' not found

Controller

```
 public function siteadmin_update_ads(Request $request)
    {


        $post = $request->all();
          $cid=$post['id'];  
         // $img=$post['ads_image'];

        $v=validator::make($request->all(),
                [
                    'ads_title'=>'required',
                    'ads_url' => 'required',

                ]
                );

        if($v->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }

         //$image = Image::find($cid);

        else 
        {
            $image = Image::find($cid);
            if($request->hasFile('ads_image'))
            {
                    $file = $request->file('ads_image');
                     $destination_path = '../assets/adsimage/';
                   $filename = str_random(6).'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
                   $file->move($destination_path, $filename);
                   $image->file = $destination_path . $filename;
            $data=array(

                'ads_title'=>$post['ads_title'],
                'ads_url'=>$post['ads_url'],
                'ads_image'=>$post['ads_image'],

            );
        }
        //  $image->caption = $request->input('caption');
        // $image->description = $request->input('description');
         $image->save();

        }
        // $i = DB::table('le_color')->where('id',$post['id'])->update($data);

        $i=Ads_model::update_ads($data,$cid);

            if($i>0)
            {
                Session::flash ('message_update', 'Record Updated Successfully');
                return redirect('siteadmin_manageads');
            }

        else {
 return Redirect('siteadmin_editads');
```

}
 }

Model

```
public static function update_ads($data,$cid)
    {
      return DB::table('le_ads')->where('id',$cid)->update($data);  
    }
```

View

```
<div class="item form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Upload Image*</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <input type='file' id="field" class='demo left' name='ads_image' data-type='image' data-max-size='2mb'/><br>
      <img src="{{ url('../assets/adsimage/').'/'.$row->ads_image}}" style="height:90px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `Image` ? Is it a Model or `Intervention` Package ?

Comment: i am trying update my previous image using form

Comment: But what is `Image` here: `$image = Image::find($cid);`, that is what I am concerned with

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is that `Image`, so I am at least possible help to you. But I'll try to solve it.

What you can do is:

Add backslash `\` before the `Image`. It should look like this: `\Image::find($cid);`

Or else, it is a Intervention package: you need to import the Facade of Intervention Package.

add `use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;`

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the 'use' import statement for class image so its trying to find the class in the current namespace which is wrong assuming your model is stored at App namespace then add the below in the begining of controller

```
use App\Image
```

Comment: But it shows FatalErrorException in SiteadminController.php line 1719:
Class 'App\Image' not found